# Partialy type Flow.js

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I have flow.js type definition as shown below:

```
export type Block = {
  color: {
    primary: Color,
    secondary: Color,
  },
  font-size: '16px',
  font-weight: '500',
};
```

And I would like to create an object with not all properties defined and another one with all fields required.

So second one:

```
const divv: Block = {
 ...all fields here
}
```

first one (just font-size):

```
const divv2: Block | any = {
 font-size: '17px'
}
```

As you can see I've used

> Block | any

To declare first one divv, but intellisense will hint me all divv2 properties, but it has only one of main Block type.

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [$Shape](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-shape)

> Copies the shape of the type supplied, but marks every field optional.

So, it'll be:

```
const divv2: $Shape<Block> = {
  font-size: '17px'
}
```

Comment: Awesome! That's it. Thanks :)